# What was the first alien species on Earth in Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who, aliens

My question is relatively simple. I would like to know what the first alien species to make its way to Earth is in the recorded and unrecorded history of *Doctor Who*.

Comment: In-universe, or first aired episode?

Comment: To expand on amflare's comment, do you mean the first aliens to appear in the show, or the first to appear chronologically?

Comment: To clarify, what would you consider to be *alien?* Do they have to be non-earth native sentient beings, or can they just be non-human sentient beings?

Comment: I meant in-universe. And I have eliminated then anti-Racnoss sentiment. And I also meant non-earth native sentient beings, i.e. the Silurians.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first aliens to appear on the show were the Gallifreyans, the Doctor and his granddaughter Susan, in the first episode.

Assuming, however, that you mean the earliest in Earth's history, that would probably be Scaroth, the last of the [Jagaroth](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Jagaroth), from "City of Death."  The explosion of Scaroth's (cool-looking spherical) ship led to the creation of the first life on Earth.

EDIT:  And since the question no longer excludes the Racnoss (as it did originally), then the answer is (of course) the Racnoss, since the whole planet coalesced around them originally.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68454/discussion-on-answer-by-buzz-what-was-the-first-alien-species-on-earth-in-doctor).

Answer (score 4):

Daleks, on 1964/11/21: [The Dalek Invasion of Earth](http://www.bbc.co.uk/doctorwho/classic/episodeguide/dalekinvasion/)

Though Time Lord or Gallifreyan would be technically correct.

Comment: This answer is categorically incorrect.

Comment: You have a better answer for the same interpretation of the question? Earliest broadcast of a Doctor Who episode in which an alien species other than the Doctor's visits Earth?

Comment: OP didn't specify "other than the doctor", which makes this answer incorrect in regards to broadcast date. And the Daleks definitely weren't the first in-universe, so the answer is incorrect in regards to that as well.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that the answer is the Racnoss. They arrived as the solar system was forming and their ship became the nucleus about which the Earth formed. And in spite of that, the Empress survived until she met the Doctor and Donna.

In the 2006 Christmas Special *The Runaway Bride*, the Doctor takes Donna back to the time when the earth was forming, and showed her that it was a Racnoss spaceship that formed the core around which the Earth formed.

> DOCTOR: We've gone back four point six billion years. There's no solar system, not yet. Only dust and rocks and gas. That's the Sun, over there. Brand new. Just beginning to burn.
>
> DONNA: Where's the Earth?
>
> DOCTOR: All around us in the dust.
>
> (Snip)
>
> (A large rock drifts past.)
>
> DONNA: I think that's the Isle of Wight.
>
> DOCTOR: Eventually, gravity takes hold. Say, one big rock, heavier than the others, starts to pull other rocks towards it. All the dust and gas and elements get pulled in. Everything, piling in until you get
>
> DONNA: The Earth.
>
> DOCTOR: But the question is, what was that first rock? 
>   (A seven pointed star spaceship comes out of the dust cloud.)
>
> DONNA: Look.
>
> DOCTOR: The Racnoss.

Comment: @user14111 While you have a point, I can't help but feel this is actually the right answer, in spite of the OP's preferences. It would have been different if the OP would have explained _WHY_ they don't like the Racnoss.

Comment: @user14111: Then the question should ask about the **second** species on Earth, not the **first**. The only valid explanation for OP's exclusion of the Racnoss (that I can think of) is that OP is interested in aliens that _visited Earth and the life on Earth_, rather than visited the location that would become the habitable Earth in the future. But that would then also exclude many others (like Scaroth, who died before Earth had life on it, even though one caused the other)

Comment: @user14111: I disagree on the shrug. If the OP is excluding certain answers, it's relevant to know the **criteria** for the exclusion. The Racnoss must be excluded for a logical reason; and this may also apply for other viable answers; hence the importance of knowing the criteria. If the OP is **only** excluding the Racnoss (for no logical reason, it just is what it is), then it's still relevant to mention that **any other answer will be considered correct**, even if they arrived under similar circumstances as the Racnoss.

Comment: As written, it would appear because "make its way to Earth" is different from "make its way to a proto-planetary disk where Earth then forms". If you go further back, possibly the pilot of Terminus - since the fuel explosion triggered the Big Bang, arguably it had made it's way to the earliest existence of every point in the universe.

Comment: Racnoss are in Earth not on it. When they came there was no Earth.

Also the questioner can ask what ever they want, with restrictions on what they are expecting as points of order. They set the scope.
No one is forcing anyone to answer

Answer (score 3):

If you take the term "alien" with more of a cultural than literal definition, the Silurans were probably the first non-human sentient life to live on Earth.

[image: Siluran]

They were around far far before humans, hiding underground in hibernation to avoid the near cataclysmic event that ended up being the capturing of our moon.

In a literal sense, the Silurians are not aliens, because they appear to be native to earth. But they would seem alien to any human who encountered them. After all, they are *green*.

Comment: You know that any Earth creature doesn't count, because the visit of the Jagaroth predates _ALL_ life on Earth. Also, the name Silurians is technically not correct. They did not live in the Silurian age, but in the Eocene, which makes them much younger than they sound; they're only a few dozen million years old. I'm sure you can find Earth creatures from longer ago.

Comment: @MrLister sure, the Jagaroth predate life on earth (except the Racnoss), but my answer is still useful for a couple reasons: 1. Jagaroth are only from the original series which some people may be less interested in. 2. Earth was basically just a rock when the Jagaroth visited, so like the Racnoss, those first visits didn't have much to do with earth *after* it became earth in any meaningful sense, even though they were formative in Earth's development.