# What was the first alien species (not Time Lords, broadcast order) on Earth in Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

Since [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173740/what-was-the-first-alien-species-on-earth-in-doctor-who) is (so I've been told in comments) not asking this question, I'll ask it.

When was the first broadcast of a Doctor Who episode in which an alien species other than Time Lords visit Earth, and which alien species was it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[The Dalek Invasion of Earth](http://www.bbc.co.uk/doctorwho/classic/episodeguide/dalekinvasion/)** was first broadcast 21 November 1964.  The first episode of the serial was *World's End*, and is the first to feature aliens other than the Doctor and Susan on Earth.

First Doctor serials, in broadcast order:

- *An Unearthly Child* The Doctor is introduced and they travel back to pre-historic times.  Takes place on Earth. No aliens.
- *The Daleks* - They travel to a distant planet - Skaro - and meet the Daleks and the Thals.  Takes place entirely on Skaro.
- *The Edge of Destruction* - everyone loses their memory and goes nuts.  Takes place aboard the TARDIS.
- *Marco Polo* The crew meet Marco Polo during one of his expeditions. Takes place on historic Earth. No aliens.
- *The Keys of Marinus* Various adventuring with aliens. Takes place on the planet of Marinus.
- *The Aztecs* Back to historic Earth again, the crew encounter the Aztec culture.  No aliens.
- *The Sensorites* Humans cause trouble on an alien planet.
- *The Reign of Terror* Historical France during The Reign of Terror. No aliens.
- *Planet of Giants* On Earth again, in (1960) modern times. No aliens, just a shrunken crew.
- *The Dalek Invasion of Earth* Earth, sometime after 2164. The Daleks have invaded. Farewell Susan.

Interestingly, the Daleks weren't the only additional aliens on Earth in the invasion.  The black Dalek had a cute little pet called a Slyther.

[image: d'awwww]

Here's the first episode of the serial:

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4jy0q9

Answer (score 1):

I think it was Daleks, on 1964/11/21 in [The Dalek Invasion of Earth](http://www.bbc.co.uk/doctorwho/classic/episodeguide/dalekinvasion/)

Comment: While I think this is correct, this answer would be greatly improved by expansion -- more details, perhaps a photo of the Daleks as the Doctor encountered them in that story arc.  Given this was only the second or third story arc for *Doctor Who* it's unlikely any other aliens beat the Daleks to Earth, unless they went unnoticed.

Comment: It was the second story of series two so 10th story overall (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_serials#Season_1_(1963%E2%80%931964) )

Comment: Also as a comment on the timings still originally the series was conceived to have educational interest so in general the earth based stories were of historical nature so tended to be historically accurate (ish?) and thus less aliens. In the early days they tended to alternate historical/sci fi (though you need to define where the stories start and end for that to work properly).

Comment: Having just read through the wikipedia summaries of the earlier stories I agree with this answer. I will admit that I didn't actually read the Dalek Invasion of Earth but am fairly confident that it probably involves Daleks on Earth. ;-)

Comment: It was in [The Daleks](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Daleks_(TV_story))- The second story of the first series, i.e. just after An Unearthly Chiild

Comment: @GerryColl: In the Daleks I am pretty sure they are off earth (and on skaro) for the entire thing...

Comment: @Chris - yeah, sorry misread the question